# map < double, multimap <int, class *> = list <class * > *L

Tags: c++, maps

I have a map
 `map < double, multimap < int, class * >> N;`

```
typedef list <class *> classList; 
classList *L;
```

I want the `class *`to go from `map <double, multimap < int, class*>>` to go into list `L;`

```
map < double, multimap < int, class* > :: iterator Mit;
multimap < int, class* > :: iterator mmit;

for ( Mit = N.begin(); Mit != N.end(); Mit++) {
  for (mmit = Mit->second.begin(); mmit != Mit->second.end(); mmit++){
//HERE
}}
```

this will compile and run. But I cannot set the two `class *` to be equal.
I get compile errors:

```
L.insert(mmit->second);
error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<Class *> :: insert (Class*&)'
```

If I put `L.insert(mmit->second);` where //HERE is i get this compile error.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::list<Class *> :: insert (Class*&)
```

Comment: You need to show your full source that one would be able to try and to compile.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Not really the _full code_ but a [MCVE].

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ True; and proper formatting for easy reading as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [`std::list::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) overload that takes a single parameter. The simplest way to add an element to the list is [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back) or [`push_front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_front).

```
L->push_back(mmit->second);
```

Note: your question says `L` is a pointer so I use pointer dereference here.

Comment: when I use `L->push_back(mmit->second);` the program will compile but it does not load the List properly because i get a seg-fault

Comment: @SimpleJack: Is `L` really a pointer? Did you use `new` to allocate memory and construct the object it points to? To be honest, I would declare `L` as an object `classlist L;` and use `L.pushback(...);`. I generally avoid dynamic allocation in most situations.

Comment: Of course I meant `L.push_back(...);` in the previous comment but I'm a terrible typist and it's too late to edit.